# DialogFlow connector for Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio, chatbase

I search for a DialogFlow / Chatbase connector for Google Data Studio.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think such a connector exists. I'm interested in your use case here; what are your objectives?

Comment: Hi Justin! I want to be able to show hight level KPI for specific audience and maybe merge chatbase data with others sources of data like Google analytics, Adobe Analytics and backend data.

Comment: Got it. We (Chatbase) are doing some work that may help you here, stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full list of available connectors [here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-sources). Chatbase and DialogFlow are not included. DialogFlow actually provides an [analytics](https://dialogflow.com/docs/analytics) dashboard showing usage and NLU data, if that's what you're looking for. As for Chatbase, frankly, I don't get what you want to achieve, since it is already a chatbot analytics platform.

Comment: The analytics dashboard in Dialogflow is powered by Chatbase, actually, but it's just a subset of reports. The full suite of Chatbase reports is available to DF users via the Chatbase API.